# SSIS Merge trigger

Tags: ssis

I'm new to SSIS and Merge triggers.

I have an SSIS package that runs daily. It reads the data from a source table and performs a lookup on the dimension table and then it fires a Merge trigger that helps it decide whether to insert or update.

My problem is when I first load the data and my destination table is empty it inserts all the records from the source into my target table(using no match on the lookup), which is correct. When there is an update on the source and I re-run the package the update does not reflect in the destination table (using no match on the lookup). But when I use match output on the lookup the update works perfectly.

Please advise.

Comment: I guess it's set up wrong. A screenshot might help. Are the databases on the same server? Are you actually using a database trigger? Are you saying the database trigger isn't merging as you expect, but if you build it manually in the package, it does work?

Comment: What is a "merge trigger"?

Answer (score 1):

I can see you haven't understand the use of Look up transformation, it is similar to `merge` in sql. One output of look up is `no match output` and another is match output, Look up automatically redirect rows to match output and does update on table when u rerun package if there are any changes to the row data. Use `conditional split` for updating existing records.

[image]